# When building a native image I faced: Discovered a type for which getDeclaringClass0 cannot be called: x2006.sharedTypes.STConformanceClass

Tags: java, quarkus, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

Framework: Quarkus 
JVM: OpenJDK Runtime Environment GraalVM CE 22.3.0 (build 17.0.5+8-jvmci-22.3-b08)
OS: macOS Monterey, Chip: M2

Command to get this error: `mvn clean package -Pnative -DskipTests`

When building a native image I faced this error:

```
Error: Discovered a type for which getDeclaringClass0 cannot be called:
org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.sharedTypes.STConformanceClass$Enum. This error is reported at image build time because class org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.sharedTypes.STConformanceClass$Enum is registered for linking at image build time by command line
com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError$UserException: Discovered a type for which getDeclaringClass0 cannot be called: org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.sharedTypes.STConformanceClass$Enum. This error is reported at image build time because class org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.sharedTypes.STConformanceClass$Enum is registered for linking at image build time by command line
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError.abort(UserError.java:85)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.FallbackFeature.reportAsFallback(FallbackFeature.java:248)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.runPointsToAnalysis(NativeImageGenerator.java:776)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.doRun(NativeImageGenerator.java:578)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.run(NativeImageGenerator.java:535)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.buildImage(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:403)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.build(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:580)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.main(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:128)
Caused by: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnsupportedFeatureException: Discovered a type for which getDeclaringClass0 cannot be called: org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.sharedTypes.STConformanceClass$Enum. This error is reported at image build time because class org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.sharedTypes.STConformanceClass$Enum is registered for linking at image build time by command line
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.SVMHost.handleLinkageError(SVMHost.java:444)
```

My problem is, when I'm trying to find the implementation of this class, I did not find anything. I know if I find the implementation and I add it to pom and reflect-config.json my problem be solved.

I tried to add
`--initialize-at-run-time=org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.sharedTypes.STConformanceClass`
into pom and this line into reflect-config.json

```
{
    "name": "org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.sharedTypes.STConformanceClass"
  }
```

Update:

The problem is solved this way:

```
    <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
          <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
          <version>5.2.3</version>
          <exclusions>
              <exclusion>
                  <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                  <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
              <exclusion>
                  <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                  <artifactId>poi-ooxml-lite</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
              <artifactId>poi-ooxml-full</artifactId>
          <version>5.2.3</version>
      </dependency>
```

Comment: Use quarkus-poi extension instead of apache-poi

see : https://quarkus.io/extensions/io.quarkiverse.poi/quarkus-poi